# juju 2.2.2 options bootstrapping vsphere essentials based controller, 3 node cluster with HA (esxi 5.5)

Tags: juju, vmware, cloud

I recently installed juju 2.2.2-xenial-amd64 onto a 16.04 desktop. Can I specify the datastore to use when bootstrapping to a local vsphere cloud? I have a vmware VSA based on esxi 5.5 in a three node cluster and the host datastores are all consumed by design by the three VSA guests which in turn make them available to the cluster as three HA datastores.  I want to be able to force the bootstrap  to 'install' to one of the HA datastores. When I try to bootstrap it always defaults to the first data store in my datacenter which is a host data store and has no space. It downloads the ubuntu server ova but when it tries to start it fails as it's trying to use a datastore with no space, there just happens to be a tiny amount of room on each host datastore to get the ova (about 2gb). I have no control over that datastore - all three host datastores are consumed by the VSA guests and re-exported to the cluster using NFS as new HA datastores.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was searching for the same information:

juju bootstrap kube-your-cloud --config datastore=datastore1

Comment: That allows it to install properly, thanks for finding that.  Now it gets it up and running but the juju controller vm is running in host only network mode and the bootstrap can't connect to it and times out the bootstrap process after 20minutes. Any suggestions on a config I need to do to make the neworking work?

Comment: Well blow me down. By manually moving the juju controller vm after its started into the VM network using the vcenter mgmt tool before the bootstrap times out it hooks up and configures the controller.  Now to play.